# Trying to CREATE TABLE in SQL Server with table-valued column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute the following:

```
CREATE TABLE *table name*
    [Id] int,
    [Country] [dbo].[Country] NULL,
    more columns...CONSTRAINTS
```

The table `[dbo].[Country]` exists and is populated, but SSMS flags `[Country] [dbo].[Country] NULL` with an error

> Column [Country] has an invalid data type

and fails with the message

> Column, parameter, or variable #8: Cannot find data type dbo.Country

when I run the statement.

Comment: That's correct.  `NULL` isn't a data type.  What data type is `[Country] [dbo].[Country]` supposed to be?  Numeric? String? Binary?

Comment: Every columns must be a defined type - `INT`, `BIT`, `VARCHAR(n)` etc. - what type is `Country` supposed to be?? You can't have other table names as datatypes....

Comment: Please consult the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to reference the primary key of the table `Country`, thus creating a foreign key. Your `Country` column should have the same datatype as the primary key on the `Country` table.

Comment: This caused me to revisit the original table that I had generated the CREATE TABLE script from. The script generator created the [Country] [dbo].[Country] column. Looking at the original, I think that there could be a glitch in the generator, since the column name - [Country], table name [dbo].[Country], and key field [Country] are all the same. When I changed my script to the key field type of the [Country] column, it ran. Thanks.